# Angular - CSS not working in Parent/Child relationship with <ng-content>

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I have an Angular Component with below Template and CSS

(**You can see all the actual files here** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gevd5i)

**Component**

- complex-template-demo.component.ts

**CSS**

- complex-template-demo.css

It displays on UI as shown below:

[image]

Next, I break this template in two component and used .

- /custom/custom-template-container.component.ts
- /custom/custom-template-item.component.ts

Then I used these two components in another component.

- custom-complex-template-demo.component

But this time it displays on UI as show below:

[image]

**Why my CSS is not working in this case?**

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: i couldnt follow the demo on the stackblitz .. but when in angular the styles are scoped on the component level and not passed to child components. In order to do this you have to use the ng-deep selector

Comment: @C_Ogoo I tried :host  ::ng-deep on stepcompleted css but that didn't help.